# ElasticSearch: Why all my text fields in the index have keyword type?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I pushing new documents using NEST in pair with class with attributes.
Here is how I define a class:

```
public class PatientNestModel
    {
        [Text]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Text]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Text]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        [Date(Format = "dd-MM-yyyy")]
        public DateTime BirthdayDate { get; set; }
        [Keyword]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        [Text]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        [Nested]
        public List<AdditionalContact> AdditionalContacts { get; set; }
        [Boolean]
        public bool Active { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is how I pushing it:

```
var response = _esClient.Index(model, idx => idx.Index("patients_esindex"));
```

But then my index metadata looks with keyword type.

```
{
    "state": "open",
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "creation_date": "1543806292300",
            "number_of_shards": "5",
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "uuid": "3_J5ck_CTaCLEdhIbCC0ZQ",
            "version": {
                "created": "6030199"
            },
            "provided_name": "patients_esindex"
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "patientnestmodel": {
            "properties": {
                "firstName": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "ignore_above": 256,
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "lastName": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "ignore_above": 256,
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "gender": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "ignore_above": 256,
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "birthdayDate": {
                    "type": "date"
                },
                "phone": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "ignore_above": 256,
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "active": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "middleName": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "ignore_above": 256,
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aliases": [],
    "primary_terms": {
        "0": 1,
        "1": 1,
        "2": 1,
        "3": 1,
        "4": 1
    },
    "in_sync_allocations": {
        "0": [
            "DCbu6-HvQT2ziCzhFZKU6A"
        ],
        "1": [
            "9SGADbBfSWuH7AanJUGgRA"
        ],
        "2": [
            "dPmhURTzTVWFV4z6Fh8ctw"
        ],
        "3": [
            "RHX67o0QQsueD6G67IXAkg"
        ],
        "4": [
            "aoBxi-i8Q1aVSeq1tT69Lw"
        ]
    }
}
```

But then I am able to find the needed document by text search only if I used the term with `.keyword`

What am I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from ES 5.0, the string field has split into two new types: text, which should be used for full-text search, and keyword, which should be used for keyword search.

https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings

Comment: I understand this but look into my NEST class. I've defined properties with text type. The main questions why they became a keyword in the ES? How should I change my class to index them as text ?

Comment: You need to define the mapping of index before sending data to index. This way you have more control on the data type of fields.

Comment: @NishantSaini I tried this way, but I received the next error each time during indexing: 
`Rejecting mapping update to [patients_esindex] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type`
Unfortunately I can't resolved this error

Comment: In elasticsearch 6.x you can't have more than one mapping types. If you want the update the data types of fields in mapping all you can do is delete and recreate the index. **Warning:** Doing this you will loose the current data which you have to reindex again.

Comment: @NishantSaini I got this, but if I creating an index using mapping I can't then add a new document from c# code using `_esClient.Index(model, idx => idx.Index("patients_esindex"));`
Seems like I definitely missing something in my c# code

Answer (score 0):

[With Attribute mapping, you must call `AutoMap()` when creating the index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/attribute-mapping.html), for the mapping from the attributes to be applied to your type in the index.

If the index has already been created, you can also use `.Map<T>()` with `.AutoMap()` to create the mapping for a type in the index, but this can only be done before indexing any documents (by default, Elasticsearch will infer the mapping from the first document indexed). If a mapping already exists for the type, you will either need to delete the index and start again, or reindex those documents into a new index that contains the expected mapping.